# Updating my modifications with each git pull?

Tags: git

I use github to update a repository using git or composer. But there are some small parts I need to "patch"/modify to the core every time I do a git pull.

What is the best way to manage this so I can always apply my changes on every update, and also keep my changes stored somewhere in my forked repository if I accidently delete everything on local? ONly storing these changes on local and just denying the overwrite does not seem secure in case of local data loss.

Comment: How is this different to a fork?

Comment: Well. How do I fork something, modify the code, then fork again when their repo is updated and once again apply my code changes by having my changes in the repo, instead of overwriting the same files locally and then commiting to my own repo?

Comment: What do you mean by "delete everything in local"? What is "local"? Normally, when you clone a repo, you have a local (or "forked") repository, period. So what's the difference between "forked repository" and "local"?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common situation: Maintaining local changes while regularly updating with remote changes. The standard way to handle this is:

- clone the repo
- check out the branch you want to use (unless it is master)
- make your local modifications, and commit them
- set up git to automatically rebase when pulling: 
  `git config branch.BRANCHNAME.rebase true`, where BRANCHNAME is the local branch you use

Now, everytime you run `git pull`, git will rebase your branch onto the new state of the remote branch. This means in detail it will:

- put aside your local commit
- pull down the remote changes
- try to apply your commit on top of the remote changes

The last step may fail with a merge conflict if there are conflicting changes - then you'll have to resolve by hand.